# PHP External File Inclusion

Tags: php, include

I have an external PHP file "test.php" like so:

```
echo "Hello";
```

I also have a html file with this PHP script inside the  element:

```
<?php include("test.php"); ?>
```

Instead of getting
"hello"
The html page has
"echo "Hello";"

How can I get it so that the include statement actually executes the PHP, not just showing the actual code?

Comment: *"I also have a html file"* - as in `.html`? If so, you'll need to instruct Apache to treat `.html` as PHP. Otherwise, you can name it as `.shtml` and do an SSI; if your server supports it.

Comment: Also, make sure that test.php does indeed have the `<?php` tag. `<?php echo "Hello";`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you include a file, PHP's interpreter doesn't assume that it is PHP code. You can include plain text or binary data or ... anything, really.

Put the `<?php … ?>` tags around the code in `test.php`.